# getting foreach $key and store into difference variable

Tags: php

```
$Ascore = 30
$Bscore = 30
$Cscore = 20
$Dscore = 20     


 $data = array(
                'A1' => $Ascore,
                'B1' => $Bscore,
                'C1' => $Cscore,
                'D1' => $Dscore
                );

$highest = max($data);


 foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if($value === $highest){
    echo $key;
    //echo output (t1,t3);
    }
```

something like this
getting them store in different variables

```
$type1 = $key[0]; //this will be t1//
$type2 = $key[1]; //this will be t3//
```

My intention is to somehow make the element I found at `$key` and put them into different variable , how I'm going to achieve that? As I have the idea but I cant get it work on.

Comment: What is in `$data` array?

Comment: Can you post the values of `$highest` and `$data`

Comment: sorry i will post it now.

Comment: i just wanted to store the $key name into difference variable

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean store the keys where the corresponding value is the maximum value in the array? If so try:

```
$highest = max($data);
$max_keys = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if ($value === $highest){
        array_push($max_keys, $key);
    }
}
```

If you must have the keys in separate variables just add:

```
list($type1, $type2) = $max_keys;
```

Comment: oh no i dont wanted to store in array , i want it to be difference variable

Comment: like i am having result as t1,t3 so type1 = t1 and type2 = t3 something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading the question correctly, because it is a bit vague:

```
$data = [1,3,5,3,5];

$highest = max($data);
$result = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $data,
        function($value) use ($highest) {
            return $value == $highest;
        }
    )
);
var_dump($result);
```